# Leaflet.js найти все линии на карте

Tags: javascript, leafletjs

Имеется карта на которую добавлены линии подобным образом

```
polyline = L.polyline([[marker.getLatLng().lat,marker.getLatLng().lng], 
           [lat1,lon1]], 
           {color: 'green', id: "line"+marker.options.id}
         )
polyline.addTo(mymap);
```

Хотелось бы получить массив всех линий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не удалось вывести массив всех линий. Пришлось получать все отрисованные элементы и искать по атрибутам.

```
mymap.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer.options.color === 'green') {
        console.log(layer);
    } 
});
```